# "Close all" does not always close all on Samsung's recent apps list

Tags: samsung, android-12, recents-screen

I have noticed something peculiar regarding the "Close all" option, that appear when you press the three vertical lines (recent apps list) in the lower left corner:

Often, all visible apps slide upwards, and everything close as it should.

But sometimes all apps slide sideways off the screen, always to the left, and disappear. However, none of them are closed down, and reappear when pressing the three lines again.

Can anyone recognize this behavior, and explain what happens and why?

This is a Samsung Galaxy A21s, Android version 12, and I have not seen this behavior on any previous phone (all Android).

Comment: It is the same on my Lenovo tablet running Android 9.

Comment: Never seen it on any of my devices.  It is possible that the phone interpreted the press as a slide and slide back to homepage.

Comment: #Rohit Gupta, no I'm pressing the same way all the time. Some times the open apps slide left several times before going upwards (and then finally closing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question does really not have much attention, but nevertheless, today I found out (by accident) what the difference is:

When the three lines are pushed (show recent apps), there appear a button saying 'Close all'.
If I hit that button precisely, all apps closes as they should.

But if I am not careful, and hit the top part of the button (which technically is above the button) or the area between the button and the listed apps, then they go left, blanking the screen but without closing any of them.

I still doesn't know why this difference is there, but now I at least know how to make a 'close all' that closes all every time...

EDIT: Aaand, for everybody who have followed this so far, poking the screen besides the showed open apps (and **not** hitting the 'Close all'-button), I have found out this just cancel the 'Show all' function and return to the main screen - by sliding all open apps to the left...!

Mystery solved!